# How to specific application user in facebook

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have android application, with facebook integration

Now I need to list of users who are signup in our application using facebook, from facebook graph api

Comment: not sure what you want to do with accounts, those would be pages, not users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/me/friends/{user-id}
```

You get an empty Array if the users are not friends.

I am not sure if that was your question, it´s quite unclear. If you want to get a list of users who are using your App, then the answer is simple: it´s not possible. You need to store users in your own database after login, that´s the only way to get a list of users who authorized your App.

Comment: i have created application in fb ,it shows an error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: well, use an active (user) access token then. you either did not use a user token at all, or your user token is not valid anymore. user tokens are only valid for 2 hours by default.

Comment: how to get user list who are use my android app.

Comment: Ex: AUSER and BUser singup in my app, A and B users are friends on fb, how can we defined as fb friends

Comment: that´s what the first part of my answer is for...you can check if they are friends with that api call. just use the user token of user A and the ID of user B (where it says "user-id").

Comment: please ask your questions on stackoverflow, with new threads - but be a bit more detailed next time ;) - i don´t do personal support ;)